# Induction along a quasiisomorphism of DGAs

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-graded-algebras

Given a quasiisomorphism of DGAs $f:A\rightarrow B$ and a DG-module $M$ over $A$.
Is the canonical chain map
\[M\rightarrow B\otimes_A M  \qquad m\mapsto 1\otimes m\]
an isomorphism on homology?

Comment: You need to take derived tensor products for this to be true.

Comment: thanks . After all this was quite a stupid question. I added a counterexample. Before I asked this question I forgot the crucial $2$ and thus it seemed as if the construction would not produce a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an elaboration on the L's comment. Let me use the cochain convention, so that the differential has degree +1.

Let $B=\mathbb{Z}/2$ (concentrated in degree 0) and let $A = \mathbb{Z}[e]/(e^2,de-2)$, where $|e|=-1$. Then the canonical projection $A\rightarrow B$ is a quasiisomorphism.

Let $M$ be the acyclic chain complex $\mathbb{Z}/2\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/4\rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2$ sitting in degrees $0,1,2$.

Since we want to equip this chain complex with an $A$-module structure, we have to figure out how $e$ could act. The Leibniz rule restricts the choices, for example if we chose multiplication with $e$ to be the zero map everywhere, the graded Leibniz rule would be violated at $\mathbb{Z}/4$.

Let $1_i$ be the canonical generator of the $i$-th chain module of $M$. If we set
$e\cdot 1_2 =2\cdot 1_1$ ,$e\cdot 1_1 =0$, we obtain an $A$-Module structure on $M$.

Now if we tensor it with $\mathbb{Z}/2$ over $A$, we get the chain complex
\[\mathbb{Z}/2\stackrel{\cong}{\rightarrow }\mathbb{Z}/2\stackrel{0}{\rightarrow }\mathbb{Z}/2\]

which is clearly not acyclic and thus the canonical map cannot be an homology isomorphism.

PS. There is another module structure on $M$; given by $e\cdot 1_2 =0$ ,$e\cdot 1_1 =1_0$ for which it works.

Comment: I also encountered an example where all DGAs are concentrated in positive degrees, Let $A=F_2{a,b,c}$ with $da=0=ab$ and $dc=ab+ba$ (all generators are in degree 1; the curly brackets should denote the free noncommutative algebra) and let  $B=F_2[a,b]$. The canonical map is a quasiisomorhpism. The Module $M$ has $F_2$ in degrees 0 and 1 and $a$ and $b$ act trivially on the generator in degree 0, while $c$ sends it to a generator of degree  1.